# consult command for isearch?

Tags: isearch, consult

I was using ivy+swiper for a while, and it has `swiper-from-isearch` which gives a nice occur-like UI for finding isearch matches. I switched to vertico + consult recently.

I see that `consult` has `consult-line` which you can bind into `isearch-mode-map`, but it's not the same, because it does regexp matching rather than literal string matching.

Is there a version of `consult-line` that matches the same way plain (non-regexp) Isearch does?

Comment: Are u using orderless? The default `completion-styles` of Emacs don't support regexp.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for. Does `swiper` do what you want? Why don't you keep using that?

Answer (score 1):

```
 (use-package orderless
 :ensure t
 :init
 (setq completion-styles '(orderless)
   completion-category-defaults nil
   completion-category-overrides '((file (styles . (partial-completion))))))
```

You have to install orderless, and consult-line with work as swiper.

Answer (score 1):

This should be similar to `swiper-from-isearch`:

```lisp
(defun consult-line-from-isearch ()
  "Call `consult-line` with the search string from the last `isearch`."
  (interactive)
  (consult-line isearch-string))
```